# How does sconstruct receive input?

Tags: makefile, scons

I want to use Sconstruct instead of Makefile. But I found that many situations in the Makefile are difficult to implement in Sconstruct.
For example,

1. I have three .c files, `a.`c, `b.c`, and `c.c`. I want to decide which file to compile into the final file based on the input. In Makefile I can use `make a`, `make b`, `make c` to achieve. But in sconstruct, `scons e` decides which statement to execute based on the final target file. Is there a way to decide which statement to execute based on the source file or a lable?
2. Sometimes in the Makefile, I want to compile multiple files at once, but not all files. In the Makefile, I can write the compilation of multiple files under one label. Is there such a method in Sconstruct?

I found a lot of documents about sconstruct on the Internet, but basically every document introduces the most basic commands.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not understanding all of the question, but SCons, builds the targets you ask it to on the command line, like Make does.  If you don't give it any, it builds the default targets, which you yourself can define through `Default()` calls.  If neither, then it builds ".", which means all of the targets discovered underneath the directory of the SConstruct.

Targets don't have to be the name of a file to build, you can use the `Alias()` function to assign a name that will work as a build target. An alias can refer to several targets if you wish, which seems to be your second question.

Feel free to hop onto the SCons Discord channel if you want to chat more interactively (see https://scons.org/contact.html for links)